# Disable checkbox dynamicly using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<ul>    
<?php  
    $q="SELECT * FROM `seat`";
    $qe=mysql_query($q);
    while ($de=mysql_fetch_array($qe)) {
        $id_seat=$de['id_seat'];
        $row=$de['row'];
        $number=$de['number'];

        for ($i=1; $i <= $number ; $i++) { 
            echo "
                <li><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"seat[]\" value=".$row[0].$i." id=".$row[0].$i."><label for=".$row[0].$i."></label></li>
            ";

        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
</ul>
```

please help.. i wanna disable checkbox so people can't use the same seat, but i don't know where and what statement that i can use to make it.. i'm tried to search but i stil don't find the answer.. i'm newbie in php.. i hope i can find solution here.. thankyou

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: way more processing is required if you plan to lock seats based on whether someone has already chosen that seat already before

Comment: Thanks for what exactly?

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">`

Comment: @AlexHowansky yes iwanna change to mysqli maybe after this this project.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can have a column in your database which stores whether the seat if free or taken like a status:

```
<ul>    
<?php  
    $q="SELECT * FROM `seat`";
    $qe=mysql_query($q);
    while ($de=mysql_fetch_array($qe)) {
        $id_seat=$de['id_seat'];
        $row=$de['row'];
        $number=$de['number'];
        $status = $de['status'];
        if($status=="ALLOTTED")
        {
            $disabledCode = 'disabled="disabled"';
        }
        else
        {
            $disabledCode = '';
        }

        for ($i=1; $i <= $number ; $i++) { 
            echo "
                <li><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"seat[]\" value=".$row[0].$i." id=".$row[0].$i." ".$disabledCode."><label for=".$row[0].$i."></label></li>
            ";

        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Also you need to add "FREE" to your status field initially and update it with "ALLOTTED" whenever it is allotted to someone.

if the seat is allotted to someone the code output will be like so:

```html
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A_ROW_NUMBER" id="THE_ROW_NUMBER" disabled="disabled"><label for="THE_ROW_NUMBER"></label></li>
```

And if it is free then the output code will be like so:

```html
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A_ROW_NUMBER" id="THE_ROW_NUMBER"><label for="THE_ROW_NUMBER"></label></li>
```

**UPDATE**

also as mentioned by Robbie Toyota and Alex Howansky you should migrate to the new PDO or mysqli as mysql_* functions have been deprecated.

Comment: @nerdy sure, please ask if you run into problems again. also consider up voting / approving the answer that helps you out so that it helps the community as well.

Comment: @nerdy kindly consider approving the answer that resolves your problem so that it helps other community users.

Answer (score 1):

HTML input elements have a `disabled` attribute, which you can use. Here's an example of what you might want to do.

I've kept your mysql_* functions in place, and all your original HTML formatting. But please look into using mysqli or PDO

```
<ul>    
<?php  
    $q="SELECT * FROM `seat`";
    $qe=mysql_query($q);
    while ($de=mysql_fetch_array($qe)) {
        $id_seat=$de['id_seat'];
        $row=$de['row'];
        $number=$de['number'];

        for ($i=1; $i <= $number ; $i++) { 
            echo "<li><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"seat[]\" value=".$row[0].$i." id=".$row[0].$i;

            if (STATEMENT_HERE) {
                echo " disabled=disabled";
            }

            echo "><label for=".$row[0].$i."></label></li>";

        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Shakti Phartiyal posted a solution a few seconds before I posted this. If you're curious, OP, I've provided the same solution, but presented in a different way. My answer does the check for the "seat is full" in the middle of outputting the data, while Shakti does the check before outputting the data. Both ways work just fine.

Comment: @RobbieToyota thank you so much for answering... i'll try it